# Retrieving a complete list of Windows processes in C

Tags: c, windows, winapi, windows-7

I am developing a simple process statistics collection library for Windows. I'm enumerating the processes with `EnumProcesses()` function, and I try to open them with `OpenProcess()` call with PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION flag. The latter one fails for a bunch of system processes, though. At the same time, I see that similar applications (sysinternals tools, task manager, etc) seem to be able to retrieve information about these processes even without requiring Administrator privileges. I tried enabling the SeDebugPrivilege privilege, but it did help only when I ran my program as an Administrator -- and still, I could not open the Idle process, the System process and the audiodg process (I would like to be able to retrieve their information for consistency as well).

So the question is: how can I get information about *all* the processes (I see it done by 3rd-party applications, but I don't see how)? Is it possible to do it without Administrator privileges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you familiar with [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and this function as well [Process32First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I have found this [code-project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6072/Win32-APIs-for-Process-Retrieval) When I used it a while ago it helped me a lot ...

Comment: Ohh you wrote windows 7, I don't know if it works on top of win7 for non-privileged user, let me know if it works.